Add layout update in category not working magento 2.2.11
I am just trying to add a custom layout update to one category.
When I click in this category on design->layout update xml there nothing happens and there is always "no update" to see. I tried in the main category as well - same issue.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thanks,
Chris
